# Fragmented contours

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm writing simple application on android using open cv that will draw red contours on black detected objects.

Here is the processing code

```
    Mat hsv = new Mat();
    Mat maskInrange = new Mat();
    Mat dilateMat = new Mat();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours= new ArrayList<>();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaImage, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);
    Scalar upperThreshold  = new Scalar(15, 15, 15);

    Core.inRange(hsv, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold, maskInrange);

    Imgproc.dilate(maskInrange, dilateMat, new Mat());

    Mat h=new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(dilateMat, contours, h, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Imgproc.drawContours ( rgbaImage, contours, -1, new Scalar(255,0,0), 1);
```

The problem is that instead of one big contour representing the object there are many little unstable contours.
[image]

I guess it's about noise, but what should be the next step in improving the app?

Comment: You may want to share your original image so that we can help improve your algorithm :-)
For the image you have, working with a threshold or adaptive threshold would most probably solve your task.

Comment: It is real time processing from camera, not only for this image. Other objects look similar

Comment: A solution will depend a lot on the type of object and background, so I doubt that it will be possible to detect any object in front of any background with this approach. What does objects or backgrounds have in common?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is nothing in common what objects have. The idea was to create an app that will create contours on objects that are in the HSV range, and the objects are not given a priori, so they are not specific objects. So it is quite difficult to make it universal? I thought that if objects has a uniform color it wouldn't be a problem...

Comment: If you have a look at the background of the image you provided, it is also true for the floor that parts of it have the "same" colour. You may have to reframe your task a little bit.